# Graylog Problems with create alert notifications

Tags: graylog2

I create alerts with this topic
But I dont understand why some information dont send. Like this variable ${message.fields.name} and another similar.

This is my Conditions
[image]

I used this template

```
Date: ${check_result.triggeredAt}
Stream ID: ${stream.id}
Stream title: ${stream.title}
${if stream_url}Stream URL: ${stream_url}${end}

${if backlog}Last messages accounting for this alert:
${foreach backlog message}
Message: ${message.message}
Source: ${message.source}
Full Message: ${message.fields.full_message}
${end}${else}<No backlog>
${end}
```

And have this in my mail

```
##########
Alert Description: Dummy alert to test notifications
Date: 2017-09-11T18:48:33.664Z
Stream ID: 59b695542ab79c0001554b85
Stream title: New Stream
Stream description: Test notifications
Alert Condition Title: Test Alert
Stream URL: https://mysite

Triggered condition: d91e0fa5-867c-4cf1-bf0e-2b5d2fdd19f9:dummy={Dummy alert to test notifications}, stream:={59b695542ab79c0001554b85: "New Stream"}
##########
Message: Full Message:
```

How create this notifications?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how, but now its work.

```
${if backlog}
You have new request: 
${foreach backlog message}
status: ${message.fields.status}
firstname: ${message.fields.name_first}
lastname: ${message.fields.name_last}
phone: ${message.fields.phone}
email: ${message.fields.email}
source: ${message.fields.source}
timestamp: ${message.fields.timestamp}
${end}
${else}
Empty backlog
${end}
```